# What is the main Ad's and Con's using MS Graph API vs MS Azure SDK

Tags: groovy, azure-active-directory, jira, azure-sdk-python

We have teh need to interact with our customers AD from Jira in order to handle automatically user onboarding.

For that we have 2 deifferent approach :

1. **Using Microsoft Graph API**
   We call directly from Jira Script Runner plugin using groovy script POST and GEt methods, this directly within Jira environment
2. **Using Microsoft Azure SDk for python**

Using this approach will need to build a python script which is store in the dedicated location on the VM and calling that scrip from Jira using Groovy script

In the first approach we are using only 4 API call only for how request and we are all time scripting within Jira environement.

ON the second approach we need to deal with 2 types of script ( python and groovy)

Based on your advise, do you see what could be the best based on your experience in order to help me chose one or the other ?

Thanks for help
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api

> We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD
>   Graph API to access Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) resources. Our
>   development efforts are now concentrated on Microsoft Graph and no
>   further enhancements are planned for Azure AD Graph API. There are a
>   very limited number of scenarios for which Azure AD Graph API might
>   still be appropriate;

Hence I will suggest Microsoft Graph

Comment: Thanks for your reply laurent, the problem is that in our context the source of the Onboarding request is Jira Service Desk, so we need to send those request from Jira to AD, how would you do to make Jira request to be received by Microsoft Graph ?

Comment: we are using this for adding guest user, so I guess it is Microcroft Graph correct ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I won't comment in too much details since I'm not working in Graph or AD team, but the idea is that you should use Graph until you need something that is not yet on Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow up to Laurent, and say, the better solution is the solution that has the least amount of complexity while accomplishing everything you need to do. 
In this case according to your own post, that is clearly just calling graph API directly from your groovy scripting in Jira.